# PHP $MySqli->fetch Always Returns 0 Results from MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysqli

This code always returns 0 even though a direct sql test returns 1 result. I error checked throughout the entire code to see if each step returned true or a result. I think, I'm forgetting something obvious, but I'm so frustrated I can't see it.

```
// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);}

//--------------------------Connection Successful -----------------------------//
$t1 = "SELECT * FROM `customer_info` WHERE `transaction` = ?";
$transaction = "345673245Vkd_";

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    printf('connect error (%d) %s', $mysqli->connect_errno, htmlspecialchars($mysqli->connect_error)); }


$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $t1);

if ( !$stmt ) { printf('prepare failed: %s', htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error)); }

$rc = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$transaction);
if ( !$rc ) { printf('bind_param failed: %s', htmlspecialchars($stmt- >error)); }

$rc = mysqli_execute($stmt);
if ( !$rc ) { printf('execute failed: %s', htmlspecialchars($stmt->error)); }

 mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $match['0'],$match['1'], $match['2'],$match['3'], $match['4'], $match['5'], $match['6'], $match['7'], $match['8'], $match['9'], $match['10'], $match['11'], $match['12'], $match['13']);

 print_r($match); echo "<br>";

 while($test = $stmt->fetch()){
      printf("%s %s\n", $match['0'], $match['1'], $match['2'], $match['3'],$match['4'], $match['5'], $match['6'], $match['7'], $match['8'], $match['9'], $match['10'], $match['11'], $match['12'], $match['13']);
    echo $stmt->num_rows();

}

$stmt->num_rows();
echo mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
```

this prints

```
 Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => ) 
 Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => )
```

and no errors through all the error checking.

//----------------------UPDATE ------------------------//
Removing WHERE `transaction` = ?
returned:

```
Array ( [0] => 
[1] => 345673245Vkd_ 
[2] => rem_reb_dpljnzl 
[3] => blank.email@hotmail.com 
[4] => eBook Title Example 
[5] => 302864487819 
[6] => $1.99 [7] => 1 
[8] => Remmy 
[9] => Example 
[10] => 1122 Example Drive 
[11] => United States 
[12] => MO [13] => 12345 )
```

Comment: Double check that there are rows in that table. You could remove the "WHERE" clause from the sql. If still nothing is returned, and there's rows in the table, then you know it's an issue with your code, and not the sql. If the issue persists, you can try using PDO instead of MySQLi to interact with the DB

Comment: Whay are you checking the connection worked twice?

Comment: At a glance, and given I don't know if "no errors" means a white screen then, there's a space between one of your `$stmt- >error` calls which would return a syntax error.

I tested this code myself and it works fine if you remove the syntax error. Maybe try selecting just 2 fields instead of * and then reduces your `$match` to `$match['0'],$match[`1`]`  to simplify your testing.

Comment: I removed the WHERE clause and it did return the row.

Comment: So, there's an issue with your `WHERE` then, if you got a row back. Try hard coding the where, instead of binding the value in.

Comment: .. or just make sure the transaction id you specified actually exists. Good luck :)

Comment: Ok, so what I found is, if I search by id it works fine. 

Searching by the transaction id value inside the table row has white space included in the ID. The whitespace is also referenced into a third party app... but because of the whitespace, the sql fails to return any rows... any idea on how to include whitespace in a row value?

Comment: Is the amount of whitespace fixed (always a single space, for example) or is it variable?